# Smoothing a line and creating a gradient

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm making this for a class and I have managed to create a drawing app in which the stroke reacts to the speed of the mouse and the colour of the stroke changes depending on the angle.

Link [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f54e8bbed027146d9171).

It looks really rough though, and I'd like to understand how I could smoothen the lines by connecting the strokes (so it would appear like a single stroke that is changing width) and if it would be possible to create a gradient, going from red to green. I tried to get some help from the teacher but we have approximately 10 minutes a week dedicated to getting individual assistance for our projects and it's quite hard to ask all these question and understand what is happening in the code...

Please note that I had a lot of help doing this. I previously did something similar using paper.js, but my teacher prefers me to use "pure" canvas for this. I have a background in webdesign, but it's far from programming, I just know markup language and working with html and css, occasionally using some jquery slider. So I'm entirely confused by even the simplest tutorials, I tried to follow [this](http://codetheory.in/html5-canvas-drawing-lines-with-smooth-edges/) but I don't even understand WHERE to put everything and it just didn't work.

I'd be really glad if someone could give me some help with this... ELI5, please. I'm a fast learner but I'm still in confusion mode, overwhelmed by all these lines of code I don't (yet) understand, but would really like to.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several hints:

- Set `context.lineCap='round'`.  This rounds the beginning & end of each line.  That rounding helps visually merge one line into the next line.
- Limit your lineWidth to a small range.  This makes your line visually flow better because there isn't a huge jump in size when the user makes rapid speed changes.

[image]

Here's refactored code and a Demo:

```js
// cache a reference to the canvas element & its context
// because they are used often
var canvas=$('#canvas')[0];
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//full-screen
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

// style lines with rounded end-caps & rounded joins
context.lineJoin='round';
context.lineCap='round';

var mouseX = undefined;
var mouseY = undefined;
var mouseIsDown = false;

var PI2=Math.PI*2;
var speed=-1000;
(function(){Math.clamp=function(a,b,c){return Math.max(b,Math.min(c,a));}})();

onMouseDown = function( event ){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseIsDown = true;
}

onMouseMove = function( event ){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  var previousMouseX = mouseX;
  var previousMouseY = mouseY;

  mouseX = event.pageX;
  mouseY = event.pageY;

  var dx = Math.abs( mouseX - previousMouseX );
  var dy = Math.abs( mouseY - previousMouseY );


  var speed = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

  // limit the min/max width of the line
  speed=Math.clamp(speed,2,12);

  var angle = 2 * Math.PI * Math.acos( dx / ( speed + 0.00001 ) );

  if( angle < Math.PI ){
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgb( 0, 255, 0 )';
  }
  else{
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgb( 255, 0, 0 )';
  }

  if( mouseIsDown ){
    context.lineWidth=speed;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo( previousMouseX, previousMouseY );
    context.lineTo( mouseX, mouseY );
    context.stroke();
  }
}
//drawing only is the mouse is down
onMouseUp = function( event ){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  mouseIsDown = false;
}

$( '#canvas' ).on( 'mousedown', onMouseDown );
$( '#canvas' ).on( 'mousemove', onMouseMove );
$( '#canvas' ).on( 'mouseup', onMouseUp );
$( '#canvas' ).on( 'mouseout', onMouseUp );
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Applying a gradient is much harder. You will have to:

- Save each mouse point
- Interpolate points between each mouse point so that each new point is 1px distant from the previous.
- Clear the canvas
- Redraw a line between each mouse point with each line's strokeStyle changing according to your desired gradient.